# Unable to instantiate receiver, java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

In the manifest I've declared the receiver element correctly to the best of my knowledge.
But the Receiver never gets called when I send out the broadcast. The log cat shows.

```
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.orderedbroadcastreceiver.HigherPriorityReceiver: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2333)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4899)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2328)
07-22 23:51:49.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3799):     ... 10 more
```

**Code**

```
class HigherPriorityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "HigherPriorityReceiver", 0).show();
    setResultCode(1985);
    setResultData("DOB");
    //abortBroadcast();
}
```

Comment: can you show your relevant manifest part (the receiver part of your manifest)?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

make class `HigherPriorityReceiver` a `public` class

Comment: Had the same problem due to some copy&paste. Definitely a facepalm situation ^^

Answer (score 8):

In Kotlin it must be a class, not an object.

Answer (score 4):

#### Answer

This class must be a public class

#### Code

```java
public class HigherPriorityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "HigherPriorityReceiver", 0).show();
        setResultCode(1985);
        setResultData("DOB");
        //abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```